# laravel 5.2 many to many relation retrieve data with intermediate table

Tags: php, laravel

I have tables :

> products
>
> - id
>
> categories
>
> - id
>
> product_category
>
> - product_id
> - category_id

by using eloquent model relation, how to get all product data from a specific category id?

Comment: Do you want the answerer to write both models and the query or do you have the models and relations? Please provide what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you defined relationships on your models, you can try this:

```
$productName = 'Some product';

$category = Category::findOrFail($categoryId);
$product = $category->products->where('product_name', '=', $productName)->get();
```